# It makes sense to use prepare() with a DQL query?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

Normally in my projects I use DQL queries for non-simple database statements. **Is necessary or recommendable to use the prepare() function wit DQL queries?**

I am researching about that, but in the official documentation does not tell anything about that; also is true that in it the prepare() function only is used with SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine 2 ORM queries don't even have a `prepare()` method (see the [`Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery` API](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php)).

Internally, the ORM keeps a ["dirty" state flag](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php#L433) that tells the ORM if a query needs to be re-parsed. After parsing, [that flag is removed](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.3/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php#L204-L209) and no further operations are needed when the query is executed again.

When you execute a query, it is thrown at the DBAL layer, which handles the `prepare()` call itself when needed (depending on the platform), so you don't have to manually handle that.

As you can see, things were already optimized for you out of the box.